# setAttribute won't work with ngModel in angular

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, angular6

i'm trying to auto assign ngModel while creating a html element
This is my code,

```
productName.setAttribute('[(ngModel)]', `customProductName`);
```

But i keep getting this error,

```
Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[(ngModel)]' is not a valid attribute name.
```

other html attributes work fine. Please how can i go about this, thank you.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow, would you mind sharing your code on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you? also go through how to create Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 0):

I haven't set value of ngModel as you have done, but i could suggest,
the simplest solution for setting custom model value is as below,

create a `model` interface like,

> productModel.ts

```
export interface ProductModel {
    productName: string;
}
```

And in your template,

> product.component.html

if it is input tag,

```
// other code form code here        

<input type="text" name="productName" id="productName" placeholder="Your productName" [(ngModel)]="model.productName">

// more code here
```

In component,

> product.component.ts

```
// create an instance of ProductModel instance by name variable model
model: ProductModel = new ProductModel();

// set the product name with custom value as below on ngOninit fuction
ngOninit () {
    this.model.productName = 'Custom product Name';
}
```

Please let me know if this solution is useful or not.. thanks

> Note: This is Template driven form example u can achieve this even
>   with Reactive forms also

Comment: It is not really normal to create an instance of interface. If you are later binding to a property of model you can just put your model property in the Component mode:any  = { }; That way the model will be okay with the empty product name property until it is set.